# use new operator dynamically allocate array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a question about the new operator to allocate array in c++:

```
int * foo;
foo = new int [5];
```

in this case, the foo point to a array of int, but how about change the code to:

```
foo = new int [0];
```

what is allocated and what will happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is allocated, and using that pointer will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Memory may be allocated as a result. Dereferencing the pointer is undefined, but "using" is too vague. It's allowed to copy the pointer or print its value, for example. The pointer should still be deleted.